# How to make a designation in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ and clicked somewhere accidentally and deleted all the designations, or what it's called, I don't know.

It looked like this:
[image]

And now it looks like this:
[image]

How to get them back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are called "inlay hints", not "designations", and you can find them in the settings.

You can find this under menu File (or menu IntelliJ IDEA on macOS), Settings, Editor, Inlay Hints and then under Parameter Names, Java. I think this one is "'New' expressions", but you could also enable them all.

Answer (score 2):

For IntellIJ IDEA 2022: Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Parameter names -> Java , Check this
[image]